# Laravel 5.6, встроенный bootstrap в public/css/app.css файле

Tags: php, bootstrap, laravel

Я Bootstrap  *не устанавливал* на Laravel,  но когда *подключаю файл* из папки

```
public/css/app.css
```

то *могу использовать* **Bootstrap *классы***.

Почему так ?

Если Laravel приходит со встроенным Bootstrap-ом *почему* это *не анонсируется* ?

Могу ли я рассматривать  этот файл как *полноценный*  Bootstrap ?

Для чего нужен этот `app.css` файл ?

Answer (score 1):

> Если Laravel приходит со встроенным Bootstrap-ом почему это не анонсируется ?

[Аннонсируется](https://laravel-news.com/bootstrap-4-laravel-preset)

С офф сайта:

> You can start using Bootstrap 4 beta with Laravel 5.5 with our new Bootstrap 4 frontend preset. The preset includes scaffolding for SCSS files, and imports Bootstrap 4 JavaScript plugins, jQuery, and Popper.js. As of this writing, we keep the jQuery dependency that ships with Laravel, but according to the Bootstrap documentation the jQuery slim version could be used instead.

---

> Могу ли я рассматривать этот файл как полноценный Bootstrap ?

Да.

---

> Для чего нужен этот app.css файл ?

Точка сборки для всех остальный файлов.

Answer (score 1):

> Я Bootstrap не устанавливал на Laravel. Могу ли я рассматривать этот
>   файл как полноценный Bootstrap ?

bootstrap подключается в файле
resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

```
require('bootstrap');
```

в package.json можно посмотреть используемую версию

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
```

> Для чего нужен этот app.css файл ?

app.css - результат сборки вебпаком (webpack.mix.js)